# Using ODBC in Access to connect to MS SQL Server 2012: huge time difference between calling query manually and in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I am having trouble retrieving data from an MS SQL Server 2012 in MS Access 2010 using DAO.QueryDef. The setup is MS SQL Server 2012 as a backend with a GUI implemented in MS Access 2010 using linked tables, views, pass-through queries, stored procedures and functions. The connection between the two is established via the ODBC driver "SQL Server".

When I execute the query manually, i.e. doubleclick it in the "Queries" section in MS Access, then I'm asked to input the two input parameters and it takes some few seconds for the qry to return the data (into a temp. table in the local Access GUI).

However, when I try to call certain query in VBA code, it takes about 10x the time of the manual exec or I even get a timeout (Runtime Error 3164: ODBC call failed).

The code in question comes down to:

```vb
Private Sub cBCreate_Click()
    Dim thisDb As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    [...] //File Dialog

    Set thisDb = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = thisDb.QueryDefs("qry_10")
    qdf.Parameters!parAbrg = aInputValue //from unbound combo box
    qdf.Parameters!parDate = bInputValue //from unbound combo box
    qdf.Execute

    [...] //sth else

    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set thisDb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Has anybody ever experienced this and might have a solution? Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

-Stefan

**UPDATE**

`parA` and `parB` are both input values derived from two unbound combo boxes sitting on an unbound form on which the button cBCreate is clicked. `parA` is a string consisting of 2..4 numerical characters (e.g. "2180"), `parB` is a string like a German date (e.g. "01.04.2016"). I enter them in this format when I trigger the qry manually as described above.

The qry trigger is nothing special. It retrieves data FROM a view LEFT JOINing it with one table on two IDs. The input parameters are used in the WHERE clause. This is the code:

```sql
SELECT
    {36 fields}
INTO
    tblExportTmp
FROM
    vw_09 wvn
LEFT JOIN
    tblAbger AS awg
ON
    (wvn.wOutId = awg.wOutId) AND
    (wvn.wInId = awg.wInId)
WHERE
    wgAbrg = [parAbrg] AND

    (
        (wOutTime Is Not Null AND
        CVDate(wOutTime) < DateAdd('m', 1, [parDate])) OR

        (awg.wInId Is Null AND
        awg.wOutId Is Null AND
        DateDiff('m', CVDate(wOutTime), [parDate]) > 0) Or

        (outTime Is Null AND
        DateDiff('m', CVDate(wInTime), [parDate]) >= 0)
    )

    AND
    (
        awg.wInId Is Null AND
        awg.wOutId Is Null
    )

ORDER BY
    {5 fields} ASC;
```

The file dialog is used to specify an XLSX file to which the retrieved data should finally be saved.

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, I do select `aInputValue` and `bInputValue` from said combo boxes before I click the button cBCreate which triggers the VBA code. Both view and table are linked from the same SQL Server. `wInTime` and `wOutTime` are timestamps in the original table and view but are linked as text fields because the of a mixup between US and DE timestamps.

I added error handling and it says that the query apparently times out. I set the timeout to 600 so that it does at least gives the results, however it takes much too long compared to manually executing the query.

Comment: Please post actual SQL query. Where doe the inputValues derive? Something from the file dialog?

Comment: Updated with SQL query, info about input vars.

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. If `aInputValue` and `bInputValue` are combo box values, do you select combobox items prior to running VBA code? Are both tables linked SQL Server tables? Is `wOutTime` and `wInTime` date fields (check design view of table, even though you cannot edit anything)? Also add [dbengine error handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835711.aspx) as *ODBC Called Failed* is a catch-all, generic message, not a specific description.

Comment: Can you review the SQL profiler for both vba query and direct query to be sure that sql is generated in vba correctly, especialy where conditions and their data types. Try to split the database tables/queries in separate ms access from GUI.

Comment: The `[arDate]` in the middle should be `[parDate]` too? -- Can you try to explicitly declare the parameters with their datatypes (string and date) in the query, with a PARAMETERS section or the Parameters dialog of the query designer?

Comment: Yep, `[arDate]` should be `[parDate]`, got lost in editing. My bad. However: explicitly declaring the params in the PARAMETERS section of the query and then casting the return values of the combo boxes to these data types apparently did the trick. The query via VBA now runs as fast as when I exec it manually. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a PARAMETERS section to the query, and explicitly declaring the parameters with their data types (string and date) helped.

(Kinda surprising for me, actually.)

The combobox values also must be cast to the appropriate data types.